# Why is the Windows Help & Support screen not working?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting

When I click on the icon in the Start Menu, the error is:

> **The Windows Help And Support can't start**
>
> A problem has occured with Windows Help And Support Center. For online help visit Windows Site.

Comment: Have you scanned for malware?

Answer (score 1):

See [How to Repair Windows 7 System Files with System File Checker](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) as first-aid.

If a problem is found, better check seriously for viruses.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start > Run > and then type msconfig, then hit Enter.

Then click on the Services tab. On the list there should be a mention of Help. If this service isn't running, then you won't have any help. Check to see if this service is running.